# Is there a possibility to delete a string that starts with a ">" and ends with a newline in postgresql via sql update statement?

Tags: sql, postgresql, data-manipulation

Lets say I have a database with about 50k entries in a column called `content`. 
This column contains strings which causes problems to my further work.

Now here is the thing I need to do it for all the rows inside of that table.

Any Ideas?
Here an example:

```
'user wrote:
-----------------------------------------------------
> Some text 
> that vary too much and I dont need it actually 
> here is end of the text 
The text I actually need.'
```

I would like to remove all of the unnecessary part so the only thing that is left is in this case :

```
'The text I actually need.'
```

Comment: How come the `"user wrote:` row isn't returned?

Comment: I added the escape character because : it would look like this inside of stack overflow: "user wrote:
-----------------------------------------------------
> Some text 
> that vary too much and I dont need it actually 
> here is end of the text 
The text I actually need. "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should delete all lines that start with a `>`:

```
regexp_replace(textcol, E'^>.*\n', '', 'gn');
```

The `g` flag is needed to delete *all* such lines, and the `n` flag makes the `^` match the position right after each line break.

I use an “extended” string literal (the leading `E`) so that I can write a newline as `\n`.

Comment: `SELECT regexp_replace((SELECT content FROM datasets WHERE source = 'PartnerA' and content LIKE '%wrote:%'  LIMIT 1) , E'^>.*\n', '', 'gn'); `
Ok This worked. I will try to find a way to do it for all the comments inside of content. Thank you !!